# Datepicker is not showing up on ipad Framework 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I am having really a big issue that when I am trying to display datepicker then it's not displaying on ipad and showing black overlay screen only so can anyone tell me whats the issue here. I am using framework version 1.4.2 and also I have simply place this on init of my developed page: 
`

> var
>   calendarDefault=myApp.calendar({input:'#ks-calendar-date-datetest',
>   convertToPopover: true});

` 
but still not working for ipad,
So I am getting black screen when I click on datepicker [image]

However, if I try on iphone then it's work fine

Comment: on the code you posted you have a space in your variable for `convertToPopover` which you have posted as `con vertToPopover`. I am not sure if this is the problem just what I see initially that needs fixing.

Comment: You shouldn't use a datepicker on a mobile device. If you use the HTML5 date input type you'll get a native datepicker that works much better on mobile devices.

Comment: Hi thanks, I know there are some alternatives out thr but the project is already live and I can't go and use any other alternative as if you notice I have only issue with ipad device so the solution within the framework7.